# Why is the token header not being read?

Tags: authentication, request, jwt, header

I have the following dashboard.js -

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = (require('../db'));
const authorization = require('../middleware/authorization');

router.post('/', authorization, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // from authorization middleware
        console.log(req.user);
        res.json(req.user);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        res.status(500).json('Server error');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

and then the authorization.js -

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Get token from header
  const jwtToken = req.header('token');
  // Check if not token
  if (!jwtToken) {
    return res.status(403).json('Not Authorized');
  }
  // Verify token
  try {
    const verify = jwt.verify(jwtToken, process.env.jwtSecret);

    req.user = verify.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(403).json('Token is not valid');
  }
};
```

The token header doesn't appear that it's being read. When I console.log(req.user), it comes back undefined.  Can someone please explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: What does the whole `verify` result look like?

Comment: I was able to figure this out.